# Combo box displaying whole array lis in one line

Tags: jsp, servlets, arraylist, combobox, jstl

I want a combo box in a jsp file to display a arraylist pass by a servlet but right now it is displaying the whole arraylist in one line of the combo box.
the servlet code

```
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
response.setIntHeader("default", 5);
request.setAttribute("name",":Motorola Solutions TC55");
request.setAttribute("item",list);
request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/default.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

the jsp code

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Include Manufacture name</title>
</head>
<body  >
<p id ="L1">Name :- <%=request.getAttribute("name")%></p>
<select>
<c:forEach items="${item}" var="temp">
    <option value='${temp}'>${temp}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
<button type="button" >Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

i added <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> now t
The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: you should add `jstl` jar to your buildpath .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mis-typed the name of the arraylist,

```
<select name='listSelect'>
<c:forEach items="${item}" var="temp">
    <option value='${temp}'>${temp}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

To avoid the errors like above , you should follow naming conventions as per [standards](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSTL4.html)

Comment: madethe cange now nothing is being displayed

Comment: Better to get this right end to end, rather than work around it in the JSP. Start by putting a suitably named list into the request. Then for reading that attribute, make sure you're using the right pattern.

Comment: @DrihanNanayakkarra Have you checked the console ? did you get any errors ?

Comment: @AshleyFrieze the change is not showing anything anyways thanks

Comment: @AshleyFrieze Do you say that my syntax is wrong  ?

Comment: @AshleyFrienze Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Unknown tag (c:forEach).
 - Unknown tag (c:forEach        i get this near the <c:forEach

Comment: Have you included in your `<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` in your jsp ? please update the question with your current code

Comment: include the tag library for `jstl` and change the ` items="${item}"` in your jsp

Answer (score -1):

The bug is here:

```
request.setAttribute("item",list);
```

it should be

```
request.setAttribute("items",list);
```

On top of that I think you can't use the ${items} construct on request parameters. You've not done that for the "name" attribute - for that you've read it using `request.getAttribute` so you'll need to do that in your foreach

Comment: Changes could be easily made in the presentation layer rather than the servlet. so it could be most preffered

Comment: _ so you'll need to do that in your foreach_ he is using jstl . so need of using the getAttribute here